# Dynamic allocation of array issue C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy

To be clear, my code works perfectly. The issue that concerns me is that i am unsure of my array allocation type.

My task is rather simple: i am required to do some operations within a dynamically allocated array.

Yet, the values are already given in the array. So therefore i am required to add these values in it.

To keep my vector dynamically allocated and to avoid the following situation:

```
float *p;
 p = malloc(9 * sizeof(float));
* p=2;
* (p+1)=60;
* (p+2)=-23;
.
.
.
* (p+8)=9;
```

I tried doing this :

```
float *p;
p = malloc(9 * sizeof(float));
memcpy (p, (float[]) {2 ,60 ,-23, 55, 7, 9, -2.55, -66.9, 9}, 9 * sizeof(float));
```

Now I am unsure because memcpy copies a static allocated array into my `p`. My  question is then: my array still remains dynamically allocated?

EDIT: My question refers to 2nd code.

Comment: You allocate 9 elements. Count how many fields you assign values to!

Comment: "memcpy copies a static allocated array into my p" - Where did you get this from? `memcpy` copies whatever you pass to it. The compound literal is a temporary automatic object.

Comment: @Olaf How is that, the `9 * sizeof(float)` takes care of the amount, or did I miss anything? Agree, there is excess, but that should not be a problem, correct?

Comment: @Olaf this is what i have been taught. don't bash me

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I refer to the assignments. `p[0] ... p[9]` (no idea why OP uses the additions)! Accessing unallocated memory is **always** a problem!

Comment: @Sourav  in the first code i didn't write all the values, as you can see it was just an e.g. , so Olaf rushed with his conclusion

Comment: @Olaf Ahh, right, I thought OP was _avaoiding_ that, so I did not check that part. Your comment stands then. :)

Comment: @CatalinGhita: In which way did I "rush"?? And use the index-operator; it is the same as the additions (that's how it is defined!) and way easier to read. Also make the compound literal `const`, otherwise you might make the resulting code even worse.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: As I understand he wants to use a different approach for the first code. Strangely, he uses only 9 elements in the compound literal.

Comment: @ you made me count how many fields i used. in the first code i only used  3 fields and i realise it isn't correct. But again, i was looking for the main ideea, not the fact that i intentionally missed the other 6 values.

Comment: Nice Stuff @CatalinGhita. It is also good to check the return value of the `void*` pointer from `malloc()`, just to be super safe.

Comment: @RoadRunner yes thank you.

Comment: Suggest changing your post from `*(p+9)=9;` --> `*(p+8)=9;`. That coding mis-step is distracting.

Comment: @chux you are right thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> my array still remains dynamically allocated?

```
float *p;
p = malloc(9 * sizeof(float));
memcpy ( p, (float[]){2,60,-23,55,7,9,-2.55,-66.9,9}, 9 * sizeof(float));
```

Yes.  The value of pointer `p` remains unchanged.  It still points to the memory dynamically allocated.
`p[0]`, the first element now has the value of `2.0f`,
`p[1]`, the next element now has the value of `60.0f`, etc.

---

Some coding suggestions:

```
int main(void) {
#define COUNT 9
  float *p = malloc(sizeof *p * COUNT);
  if (p) {
    memcpy(p, (float[COUNT] ) { 2, 60, -23, 55, 7, 9, -2.55f, -66.9f, 9 },
        sizeof *p * COUNT);
    //...
  }
  free(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why `sizeof *p` instead of `sizeof(float)` ?

Comment: @CatalinGhita  With `p` as a pointer, `p = malloc(sizeof *p * COUNT)` is always right, easier for review and less work to update.  If you saw code `q = malloc(sizeof *q * COUNT)`  vs. `r = malloc(sizeof (double) * COUNT)`, you would know the first is correct by just at the line.  The 2nd would need you to search for the declaration of `r` to know if it is correct.  With the 2nd, if the type pointer to should change, the coder is obligated to edit all related `*alloc()` calls.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't have an(y) **array**, all you have a pointer to a memory of particular size.

Secondly, as you mentioned, (*emphasis mine*)

> *memcpy copies a static allocated array **into** my `p`*

so, yes, the pointer still has (*or points to*) the dynamically allocated memory.

As we see from `C11`, chapter §7.24.2.1

> The `memcpy` function copies `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` into the
>   object pointed to by `s1`. [...]

So, we can see, the *objects* themselves are not changed / replaced, it's only the contents that gets copied.

Comment: The compound literal **is** an array!

Comment: @Olaf Right. Basis of my answer: _"my array....."_ which refers to `p` which is wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your initialisation values are constant, you can use a compound literal. However, the code is error-prone. If you forget one element in the literal, you will access the array out-of bounds. This invokes *undefined behaviour*.

Change three things:

```
// use a macro for the length. In general don't use magic numbers!
#define ARRAY_LEN 9

// change the compound literal to:
... (static const float [ARRAY_LEN]){ ... }
```

this avoids copying the literal every time your function executes. It also makes the literal immutable so the compiler can check if you try to assign values to it.

Note: `mempcy` does not "copy a static(ally) allocated array ...". Neither is that a requirement for your array, nor is the compound literal you use a static object, but automatic.

**Caution:** Always check the result of functions which can encounter an error if anything the function does is used for further processing. `malloc` can return a *null pointer* on error. Handle this situation appropriately!